# Can not use Spring Cloud Contract Wiremock, Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring-boot, wiremock

I tried to use Spring Cloud Contract Wiremock to test Feign client in microservce architecture with stub server, without real request to another server.
I take the example from repository **https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/tree/master/samples/wiremock-undertow/src/test/java/com/example**, just change real data for my project. My code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.gaming.jps.configuration.FeignMocks;
import com.gaming.jps.dto.paymentSystem.PaymentSystemFieldsDto;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.AutoConfigureWireMock;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;

import java.util.Map;

import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.*;
import static java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copyToString;


//@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = "app.baseUrl=http://localhost:7070", webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.NONE)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 7070)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class WiremockImportApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private Client client;

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws Exception {

        Map<String, PaymentSystemFieldsDto> response = objectMapper
                .readValue(new ClassPathResource(FeignMocks.PPS_GET_PAYMENT_SYSTEM_INFO).getFile(),
                        new TypeReference<Map<String, PaymentSystemFieldsDto>>() {
                        });

        stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/payment-systems-info"))
                .withHeader(Client.HEADER_AUTH, containing("PPS "))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                            .withBody(copyToString(
                                    FeignMocks.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(FeignMocks.PPS_GET_PAYMENT_SYSTEM_INFO),
                                    defaultCharset()
                            ))));
        assertThat(client.paymentSystemsInfo(FeignMocks.PPS_KEY, null)).isEqualTo(response);
    }

}
```

Dependency in POM:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

But when I try to run this test I am receiving exception with loadin Context:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:346)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:340)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:263)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:256)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:255)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:107)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.WireMockConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.FatalStartupException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to /0.0.0.0:7070
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:415)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.FatalStartupException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to /0.0.0.0:7070
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.start(WireMockServer.java:148)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.WireMockConfiguration.start(WireMockConfiguration.java:266)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.WireMockConfiguration.reRegisterServer(WireMockConfiguration.java:165)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.WireMockConfiguration.reRegisterServerWithResetMappings(WireMockConfiguration.java:181)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.WireMockConfiguration.init(WireMockConfiguration.java:113)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to /0.0.0.0:7070
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.jetty9.JettyHttpServer.start(JettyHttpServer.java:191)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.start(WireMockServer.java:146)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to /0.0.0.0:7070
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:346)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:307)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:231)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:385)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.jetty9.JettyHttpServer.start(JettyHttpServer.java:189)
    ... 94 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:80)
    at wiremock.org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:342)
    ... 101 more
```

I can not find in example project any properties, configuration or settings file.
Please help to understand how to fix this problem.

Comment: Check if port 7070 is already used by other applications. If you are working in OS X/Linux, use `lsof -i:7070` to find it out.

Comment: I work on Windows. But in any case when I change port to any other - the situation is same

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. Only need to remove **webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.NONE** from **@SpringBootTest** annotation. And use **@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)**

It seems that it is just mistake in repository!